# Looping through a php array => weird

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, associative-array

Need a sanity check on this one, I think I just confused myself.  I am trying to loop throught the below array and get the fields back for multiple people that are register.

```
{
 [12]=>
    array(79) {
      ["Event Number"]=> int(466226)
      ["Event Info"]=> string(134) “Event ABC”
      ["Event Acct Code"]=> NULL
      ["email"] => string(12)"email@email.com
    }
}
```

How can i best accomplish this?

This is what I tried

```
$associativeEventInfo=[];

    foreach ($res as $eventInfo)
    {
        $associativeEventInfo[]=$eventInfo;
    }
```

var dumping $associativeEventInfo returns the results

Id like to get each field out according to the array, for example

["EvenNumber"] =466226 so that I can then pass that over to database and do stuff.

Comment: made any attempt?

Comment: @Akintunde-Rotimi yea, let me edit with what I tried.

Comment: Can you better describe what the goal is? It's not quite clear

Comment: @JensV, yea.  So I am consuming an api where users are regestering for events.  Their API is returning results in that form as above.  I need to be able to loop through the results of register user and pull out their information so that I can then map it out to my database API.

Comment: You should use foreach twice to be able to get each key of your associative array. Because you have an associative array inside numeric one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the goal is to remap the data to presumably database fields. First off, accessing the fields is quite easy:

```
// Assuming $returnedData is an array of assoc array containing the data;
foreach ($returnedData as $eventData)
{
    $eventNumber = $eventData['Event Number'];
    $eventInfo = $eventData['Event Info'];
    // And so on
}
```

Remapping it is as simple as creating a new array with the correct format (one can also use `array_map` but I leave that as a readers exercise):

```
$remappedData = [];
// Assuming $returnedData is an array of assoc array containing the data;
foreach ($returnedData as $eventData)
{
    $remappedData[] = [
         'eventNumber' => $eventData['Event Number'],
         'eventInfo' => $eventData['Event Info'],
         // And so on
    ];
    $eventNumber = $eventData['Event Number'];
    $eventInfo = $eventData['Event Info'];
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.  Do you know why I would be getting a undefined index error?  I am decoding the results back with true for associative.

Comment: @jesus2kus Possibly because some data entries do not contain some array keys. If you have an associative array that looks like `$arr = ['a' => 1, 'b' => 2]` and you try to access `$arr['x']` you will get that error

Comment: @jesus2kus You seem to already use it, but using `var_dump($data)` to show the values will give some insight. You can also check if an array key exists with `isset($arr['key'])`

Comment: ah ok.  Do you know why when I var_dump $remappedData I am only getting one result?

Comment: @jesus2kus my bad, I forgot to do `$remappedData[] = ...` instead of `$remappedData = ...`. This will append an element to the array